# How to arrange websites on the same shared hosting?

Tags: iis-7, web-hosting

I have a shared hosting from godaddy and running there some website:

[example1.com](http://example1.com) community server website located in the root of the server.

[example2.com](http://example2.com) wordpress blog located inside a folder called example2.

[example3.com](http://example3.com) wordpress blog located inside a folder called example3.

and some others.

My problem is when you go to home page for any website not in the root, such as example3.com i see the url like that: http://example3.com/example3/

How to arrange my websites folders on the server so they all appear as they are on the root of the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always done this by creating virtual hosts for each domain and pointing them to a new folder in a directory such as c:\webroot\sitename.com\
This way, you can prevent anyone who tries just your IP Address from hitting any websites, or you can have better control and keep Google from indexing you twice (it can happen)

Comment: how to create these virtual hosts?

Comment: I don't think you can edit your VHosts on a shared account. There's probably somewhere in GoDaddy's management interface a way for you to specify how and where is each domain hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I know what's happening. You have installed a CMS on each domain, and you've installed it on a subdirectory in each domain (Community Server, WordPress), that's what they are shown like that.

So, you'd need to modify the *.htaccess* file in each domain and edit the *RewriteRule* lines you see there. If you post the content of that file, maybe I can help you get it working.

Comment: So the problem is in the websites its self, not in something i can manage in the hosting?

Comment: Probably. I didn't notice you're running IIS, so in that case I can't help you (I thought you were using Apache)